# Obtain the rotation vector/axis of canvas in vpython

Tags: canvas, rotation, vpython

Is it possible and if so to get the rotation vector/axis of the canvas?

I would like to implement dragging in 3D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on dragging in 3D:

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/mouse_drag.html

As for determining the current direction and position of the camera, see this:

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/canvas.html